# Limit the Primefaces datePicker minutes and seconds from Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, primefaces

I am using a datePicker Primefaces element in order to allow the user to select a value for the hours, minutes and seconds. Currently, the hour has values between 0 and 24, the minutes are between 0 and 60 and same for the seconds.

I want to limit this possibility of choice to some static values, obtained from getting the length of a video posted on the page.I have in JS the value for the hours, for the minutes and for the seconds.

So, for example, if the video has 1 minute and 30 seconds, I want the hours part not to allow the user to press the arrow up or down, the minutes to be maximum 30 and the minutes 1. I tried the below approach with JS, but I get the error: "timePicker.setMaxTime is not a function". In Java, I can set on the Primefaces datePicker minDate and maxDate, but I do not know the length of the video there, I can only find it from JS.

What can I do?

The UI datePicker element:

```
                                <p:datePicker id="timeDatePicker"
                                              widgetVar="widgetVarOfDatePicker"
                                              value="#{traineeDashboard.newIncidentTimestamp}"
                                              appendTo="@this">
                                    <f:converter converterId="timeConverter"/>
                                </p:datePicker>
```

The JS code:

```
    var timePicker = PF('widgetVarOfDatePicker'); // Replace with your actual widgetVar
    var hoursDropdown = $('div.ui-hour-picker span:eq(1)');
    var minutesDropdown = $('div.ui-minute-picker span:eq(1)');
    var secondsDropdown = $('div.ui-second-picker span:eq(1)');

    hoursDropdown.text(hours);
    minutesDropdown.text(minutes);
    secondsDropdown.text(seconds);

    if (hours == 0) {
        timePicker.setMaxTime(minutes, seconds);
    } else {
        timePicker.setMinTime(hours, minutes);
    }

    hoursDropdown.trigger('change');
    minutesDropdown.trigger('change');
    secondsDropdown.trigger('change');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be tough to accomplish because so much of the internal datepicker code is relaying on 60 seconds, 60 minutes etc.

There has been an open ticket for years: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5551

You might want to go upvote that issue but be warned none of the other PrimeFaces libs PrimeNG, etc allow this so I doubt it will be implemented.